# Get data from Cloud firestore and displays them into widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Below you can see a code where I want to display data that I have collected from a registration form in Flutter.
the registration form push the data to a collection called " user " then some other documents data are pushed as:
name - email etc...

As you can see by XXXX I want that the data I retrieve from cloud firestore be shown into the widget:
Below the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';



class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      body: MainWelcome(),
    );
  }
}

class MainWelcome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainWelcomeState createState() => _MainWelcomeState();
}

class _MainWelcomeState extends State<MainWelcome> {

  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;


  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("user").getDocuments();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Benvenuta ${element.data["name"]}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          });
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          return Text("No data");
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `FutureBuilder` widget to display the data in the widget tree:

Create a method that returns the data:

```
    Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("user")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: "email_here")
        .getDocuments();
  }
```

Then inside the `build()` method do the following:

```
          FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        title:
                            Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Ok thanks but how to put in 'Benvenuta ${element.data}', the String "name"

Comment: `element.data["name"]`

Comment: Thanks but I just see the CircularProgressIndicator running and no data

Comment: Ok but it doesnt show data just circularProgressIndicator

Comment: Hi I have still the problem how to call a emal variable to display into the widget just the data for a single user